# Is there a name for the exponent of a local representation of a holomorphic function?

Tags: complex-analysis, terminology

Let $A\subset\mathbb{C}$ and let $f:A\to\mathbb C$ be holomorphic. Then for a fixed $z_0\in A$, by a conformal change of coordinates we can write $f$ in the form (locally)
$$f(z_0)+z^n$$

Is there a name for $n$? I am thinking "order" but I haven't seen anyone use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$n$ is the order of zero of $f(z)-f(z_0)$ at $z_0$.

Comment: I am actually looking for a word that fits here (if there is one at all): "$n$ is the ___ of  $f$ at $z_0$."

Comment: No single word fills that sentence.

Comment: I just found this: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RamificationIndex.html. The definition seems to fit here. But I don't know whether I can use it here, or whether it is common.

Comment: If you use the term in that I link do people understand what you are talking about? I think it i s much better to say order of zero of $f(z)-f(z_0)$.

Comment: You are probably right. I was just trying to make my statements concise.